# All string data appears as "Instance of" when i print

Tags: flutter, text

recently i made a couple of form pages( text input,radio button, that kind of stuff), and they used to work pretty well. I came back to them after working in another part of the app, and realize that it doesn't work anymore.

I checked a couple of things and realized that all text input data comes as "Instance of thing". So when i send the data to the backend and check it, it appears as null. As far as i know this means that the string data the user input is not being saved as a string inside my variables, but as instances and that's why it doesn't work.

Any ideas as to why this happened? As far as i remember i didn't change anything in these pages.
I'm using provider to maintain the data locally.

If snippets of code are needed please ask.

Comment: Well, what exactly is *thing* and what does your code look like? Why can it even do that, aren't your variables typed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably if you are getting "Instance of thing" & also null, then you need to await on your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
class YourClass {
  int yourVariable = 0;
  String anotherVariable = "string";
  
  @override
  String toString() {
    return "YourVariable : $yourVariable , AnotherVariable : $anotherVariable";
  }
}
```

You have to override the `toString()` method and return your objects like above and call `toString()` method when you print the object